# How do I get a response status of OK as the test result?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I am using Postman for API testing. I want to get status `Ok` as the test result.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
pm.test("status ok", function() {
  if (pm.response.code === 200) {

  } else if (pm.response.code === 500) {
    if (pm.expect(pm.response.json().status).to.include("true"))
  };
```

Please could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To assert the status on a response, you can use a test like this:

```
pm.test("Status code name is OK", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status("OK");
});
```

This is one of the *Snippets*, this section can be found on the right of the `Tests` tab.

You can find this one under `Status code: Code name has string`.

Comment: I want to design a test for checking the "Status" : "True" .. How can i do that??

Comment: The word 'True' for the response status? If so, just change 'OK' to 'True'. Or is that part of the response body?

Comment: I have tried it but it give error.."Status code name is true | AssertionError: expected response to have status reason 'true' but got 'OK'"

Comment: Is that value in the response body? Can you update the question with details of the response body please.